# Image data type in SQL Server Comapct 4 & Code-First Entity Framewwork 5

Tags: .net-4.0, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce-4, entity-framework-5

My Code-First entity column is declared like this:

```
[Required, DataType("image")]
public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
```

Validations are turned off:

```
Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

And is column type is still `varbinary(4000)`.

When I try to save data, Entity Framework throws an exception:

*Byte array truncation to a length of 4000.*

How to declare that C# `byte[]` type should be mapped to `image` SQL type?

**Versions:**

SQL Server Compact 4

Entity Framework 5 RC

.NET Framework 4.0

Comment: See my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/04/saving-images-to-sql-server-compact.html The attribute should be: [Column(TypeName = "image")] public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

Comment: I know that this is possible in EF4, but there is no `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ColumnAttribute` in *EntityFramework.dll* version 5 RC.

Comment: It is in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace (moved there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this attribute:

```
[MaxLength]
```